# How to access object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var v = [{"filename":"1.mp4","resname":"1280x720","videolength":"00:00:26.07"},{"filename":"2.mp4","resname":"854x480","videolength":"00:00:26.07"},{"filename":"3.mp4","resname":"640x360","videolength":"00:00:26.07"}];
```

I am using `$.parseJSON(v);` but have error , any suggestion to get the value of `resname` ?

Comment: `v` is an array so there is no need to parse it again.. iterate over it and access the `resname` property

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L0zrebfv/3/

Comment: parsing a json will convert a string to an object. But in case you have a array not a string. so yours returned an error. Try va[0].resname for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var v = [{"filename":"1.mp4","resname":"1280x720","videolength":"00:00:26.07"},{"filename":"2.mp4","resname":"854x480","videolength":"00:00:26.07"},{"filename":"3.mp4","resname":"640x360","videolength":"00:00:26.07"}];

$.each(v,function (i, val) {
    console.log(val.resname)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to parse v you can access it in different ways

one is by iteration or forloop

```
v.forEach(function (item, i) {
    alert(item.resname)
});
```

and you can also directly access the elements by using

```
 alert(v[0].filename);
alert(v[1].filename);
```